# Django: how to exclude the bogus option '----' from select element generated from modal form field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

models.py:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    TIME_UNIT_TYPE = (
        ('D', 'Day'),
        ('W', 'Week'),
        ('M', 'Month'),
    )
    time_unit = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TIME_UNIT_TYPE)
    ...
```

forms.py:

```
class FooForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = (time_unit,)
```

When **time_unit** is rendered in the template, the resultant **select element** contains a bogus '----' option that I don't need for my app. I can remove this bogus option inside **init**() or redefine the **time_unit** attribute inside the FooForm. But I was wondering if there are any other more straightforward ways to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms as forms

class FooForm(ModelForm):
    time_unit = forms.forms.TypedChoiceField( 
                    required=True,
                    choices = Foo.TIME_UNIT_TYPE
                )    
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = (time_unit,)
```

Test if this works for you.

Comment: I have tried **empty_label** but that doesn't work, because **empty_label** is available only for forms.ModelChoiceField but **time_unit** is forms.TypedChoiceField.

Comment: I didn't know about that. Good call - [here is the docs for it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label)

Comment: @pastylegs - see my comment above.

Comment: If you look at [the code for the empty_label](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L910) you can very easily replicate that in your own __init__

Comment: @pastylegs - are you referring to the `__init__()` for `FooForm`? Or are you suggesting me to create a custom choice field in whose `__init__()` I replicate the `empty_label` code?

Comment: The later; a custom form field as opposed to a form with a custom init. Unless there is a problem with one over the other though I think you should use what's easiest

Comment: @danihp - sorry for the late acceptance. I didn't get notified by the system of the further comments, so I didn't see them until now.

Answer (score 1):

None that are particularly easier/less code. You could alternatively create your own Field for your time_unit, extend [the `_get_choices()` method](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/fields.py#L703) of the default ChoiceField and use it on your **time_unit** model field if you thought that was cleaner but that's much more work