# Removing the not selected option from a choices field in a form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django choice set which I display in a form :

```
    PRIORITIES_CHOICES = ( 
    (1, u'Low'),
    (2, u'Medium'),
    (3, u'High'),
    (4, u'Critical'),
```

Now when I disable this choice in a form it provides a not selected option which looks like -------- and the value is "". I would like to remove this field. How can I do it ?

Comment: What means 'disable choice in a form'? It is a modelform? Are this choices in the model? Is this your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220404/django-how-to-exclude-the-bogus-option-from-select-element-generated-fro ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the field requried and provide initial value. Non-required field should have a "not selected" choice.

Comment: Thanks, even that it is still weird. if I am using required = false , the for validation code getting an exception. shouldn't it just allow it ?

Comment: @Nuno_147 If the field isn't required, there should be a way for user no to fill it in. For selects it means select "empty" option. So it should be in select.