# how to delete the ---- generated by select choices

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

i have a question on how do i get rid of the ---- from the select drop down menu not to show the null(---) in the first row. I found from stackoverflow  on RadioSelect and i manage to get rid of the --- but i am stuck in the select drop down menu...:(
here is my coding example.

models.py

```
colorradio = (("1" , 'Yellow'),
              ("2" , 'Red'),
              ("3" , 'Blue'),
              ("4" , 'Black'),)
COLORRADIO = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = colorradio, null = True,  blank = True)

colorselect= (("1" , 'Yellow'),
              ("2" , 'Red'),
              ("3" , 'Blue'),
              ("4" , 'Black'),)
COLORSELECT= models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = colorselect, null = True, blank = True)
```

forms.py

```
class RadioSelectNotNull(RadioSelect, Select):

    def get_renderer(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        """Returns an instance of the renderer."""
        if value is None: value = ''
        str_value = force_unicode(value) # Normalize to string.
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs)
        choices = list(chain(self.choices, choices))
        if choices[0][0] == '':
            choices.pop(0)
        return self.renderer(name, str_value, final_attrs, choices)   

class RainbowForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Rainbow
        widgets = {'COLORRADIO':RadioSelectNotNull(), # this is correct and NOT shown ---
                   'COLORSELECT':RadioSelectNotNull(), #should be in dropdown menu
                   }
```

I did like the `COLORSELECT` to show as dropdown menu and also not showing the ---- in the first row. But if im using like the above code i get `COLORSELECT` as `RadioSelect` and NOT showing ---- (which is what i am want for not showing ---) but not as `RadioSelect`.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220404/django-how-to-exclude-the-bogus-option-from-select-element-generated-fro

Comment: Have you tried removing blank=True from the model definition?

Comment: Hi thank you for quick reply. I did try but i get an error "'module' object has no attribute 'TypedChoiceField'". what is that mean?

Comment: Hi qdot. yes i did but no luck..i did also make it blank=False and default=0 and default=1 but no luck..:(

Answer (score 1):

`models.CharField` uses `TypedChoiceField` form field when there are choices, by default. Thus no need to manually specify it (also its `django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField`).

Try to remove `blank=True` and set a default value(or providing initial value in `formfield`, normally you don't have to do this, `ModelForm` would process it for you). Also its not meaningful to have `CharField` nullable; and I'm switching variable names `COLORSELECT` and `colorselect` by convention.

```
>>> COLORSELECT = (("1" , 'Yellow'),
...               ("2" , 'Red'),
...               ("3" , 'Blue'),
...               ("4" , 'Black'),)

>>> colorselect = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=COLORSELECT, default='1')
>>> colorselect.formfield().__class__
django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField

>>> print(colorselect.formfield().widget.render('','1'))
<select name="">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Yellow</option>
<option value="2">Red</option>
<option value="3">Blue</option>
<option value="4">Black</option>
</select>
```