# Django: CharField remove default ------— choice

Tags: python, html, django

In my **models.py** I have the following CharField

```
class Method1(models.Model):
    inputfile_param     = models.FileField()
    clustering_method_param     = models.CharField(max_length=20,
         default='ward', blank=True, choices=(
         ('complete', 'Complete linkage'),
         ('average','Average linkage'),
         ('ward','Ward'),))
```

How do I remove the default --------- choice from CharField?
I tried inserting `empty_label=None` but not working.

And I cannot remove `blank=True` because it will prevent
`FileField()` failed to capture the uploaded file.

My **forms.py** looks like this:

```
class Method1ClusteringForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Method1ClusteringForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: How did you tried to put `empty_label=None`?

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov: Before `blank=True`.

Comment: Try to put `self.fields['clustering_method_param'].empty_label = None` after  `super(Method1ClusteringForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov: Doesn't work. "---" still stays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220404/django-how-to-exclude-the-bogus-option-from-select-element-generated-fro) which may be the solution for you, too.

Try:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms as forms

class Method1ClusteringForm(ModelForm):
    clustering_method_param = forms.forms.TypedChoiceField( 
                    required=True,
                    initial = 'ward',
                    choices = (
                        ('complete', 'Complete linkage'),
                        ('average','Average linkage'),
                        ('ward','Ward'),)
                    )    
    class Meta:
        model = Method1
        fields = ('inputfile_param', 'clustering_method_param',)
```

Comment: Your code works! But, how can I enable default value inTypedChoiceField? The default of `clustering_method_param ` in **models.py** is ignored.

Comment: It's ok I fixed it using `initial = 'ward'`. See my edit on your post.

Answer (score 0):

you must remove `blank=True` in your field definition. see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#blank)